# Defining a parameter as an unspecified template type

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I tried to create an SSCE, because this usually also helps to find an issue early on. However, I can't seem to find a solution for this, so I would like to know if it is possible to define an argument which is an unspecified template class pointer.

I have an interface defined, and a parser class, which should handle the implementation details for xerces (like transcoding and all this overhead). The interface class would be designed to create the objects from the (SAX)parser, but without having to deal with the xerces library.

In Java I know I could use an unspecified generic type argument like this:

```
class Parser
{
    public Parser(IGenericInterface<?> oImpl) {};
}
```

And basically I'm would like to know how this can be done in C++. In the below example I get a compiler error on the line declaring the interface variable because it is missing the type. But of course in the class declaration the type is unknown and should get assigned during runtime as shown in `main`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T>
class IGenericInterface
{
public:
    IGenericInterface() {};
    virtual ~IGenericInterface() {};

    virtual T *createInstance(void) = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Implementation : public IGenericInterface<T>
{
public:
    Implementation() {};
    virtual ~Implementation() {};

    T *createInstance(void)
    {
        T * t = new T;
        return t;
    }
};

class Parser
{
public:
    Parser(IGenericInterface *oImpl) { mImpl = oImpl; };
    virtual ~Parser() { delete mImpl; };

    void doSomething(void) {  do whatrever is needed; t = createInstance(); };

private:
    IGenericInterface *mImpl;
};

int main()
{
    Parser *p = new Parser(new Implementation<int>());
    sleep(3);

    return 0;
}
```

So how do I have to define the `Parser` constructor to make it pass an arbitrary interface argument?

Comment: Looks like what your parser does depends on the template argument of `IGenericInterface<argument>`, so why isn't `Parser` a template, too?

Comment: Don't hesitate to quote compiler errors verbatim. Indicating which line number is where also rarely hurts.

Comment: Your example never uses `CreateInstance`. I's a bit pointless to define a template if you are not going to use the only thing it offers. How are you planning to use `CreateInstance`?

Comment: @n.m., my example was designed to show what I wanted to do, not do a full implementation. In fact, I don't even have a `createInstance` function, it is just there as a placeholder, bcause the parser shoul dbe able to use the interface.

Comment: @DyP, I wanted to encapsulate the xerces library details into a single module. If I make the parser class a template, then I would have to expose this again, and then I wouldnt even need this intermediate class. If it can't be done, then I have to accept it though, and see if I can find a different way.

Comment: If you have a function that depends on a template parameter, show its signature and its intended usage. If there's no such function, there's no problem to solve.

Comment: So, if the template arguments of specializations of `IGenericInterface` cannot be known in the TUs where `Parser` is used, then no such specialization can be used in `Parser`. Note C++ class templates are *templates of classes*, not classes themselves. The template itself is not the type; for each different set of template arguments used, a new type is created. For most operations on objects, the type of that object has to be known. In the case of a template specialization this includes the template arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since apparently a generic like in Java can not be implemented in C++, I found a different solution which also allows me to keep the details of the parser separated.

The functions that should have been in the Interface class are now moved to the parser class as virtual abstract functions. The I can define a template which derives from the parser, thus be forced to implement the virtual functions, which basically is what I wanted.

The pattern looks like this now:

```
template <class T>
class ISerialization
{
public:
    virtual ~ISerialization(void) {};

public:
    virtual std::string serialize(void) = 0;
    virtual bool deserialize(std::vector<T *> &oObjects, std::string const &oSerialized) = 0;
};

class parser
{
    void parsing(void) { abstract_function(); }
    virtual void abstract_function() = 0;
};


class implementation : public ISerialization<Task>, public parser
{
    std::string serialize(void) {};
    bool deserialize(std::vector<T *> &oObjects, std::string const &oSerialized) {};
    void abstract_function() { specific implementation goes here};
};
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a static language, so any types must be resolved at compile time. Hence, what you are doing in java cannot be done in the same way in C++. Instead, you use either dynamic polymorphism (using inheritance) or "static polymorphism", using templates (resolved at compile time) with CRTP.

Comment: So with `using inheritance` you mean, in my implementation class I should inherit parser directly? That might work?

Comment: After thinking about the inheritance, I now found a pattern, which works. I like the java approach better, because you can strictly separate the objects, but since this is not possible in C++ I found a solution which is also ok. I can post an example as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing static and dynamic polymorphism is a no go (exemptions might apply)

```
template <class T>
class IGenericInterface
{
public:
    IGenericInterface() {};
    virtual ~IGenericInterface() {};

    virtual T *createInstance(void) = 0;
};
```

And your use of pointers is a nightmare.